# Media Popup filter results by custom media Category

Tags: wordpress, popup, media, categories, uploader

i'm using the wp.media for Media Uploader Popup

http://mikejolley.com/2012/12/using-the-new-wordpress-3-5-media-uploader-in-plugins/

I created a new category called 'media-category' for the Media Library, i would like to filter the results by this new category.

This is my current code:

```
custom_uploader = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media({
  title: 'Choose Media',
  button: {
    text: 'Choose Media'
  },
  multiple: true,
  library: {
      type: 'video/mp4'     
  }
});
```